# SonarQube Scanner can't parse nUnit 3 test reuslts

Tags: sonarqube-scan, nunit-3.0

It's look like SonarQube scanner 6 can't parse NUnit 3's TestResult.xml.

Is there any way to parse NUnit 3's test results into the NUnit 2 format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

NUnit 3 has a option to convert his new test results format into NUnit 2's format :

```
-result:reports\TestResult.xml;format=nunit2
```

Comment: any updates on this from SonarQube? or we have to go with NUnit2 format?